# Enabling custom auditd logging in RedHat

Tags: rhel, logs, rsyslog, audit, linux-audit

I enabled the auditd service using the following configuration to trace all user activities (belonging to group ID 555) on RedHat OS:

```
vim /etc/audit/audit.rules
-a always,exit -F gid=555 -F arch=b64 -S execve
-a always,exit -F gid=555 -F arch=b32 -S execve

vim /etc/audisp/plugins.d/syslog.conf
active = yes
args = LOG_LOCAL6

vim /etc/rsyslog.conf
local6.* @@<IP address>
```

However, for each executed command, several logs are generated (usually 3 logs), and there isn't any unique log that includes all necessary information, i.e.:

- Command
- Username
- Timestamp
- Server IP
- Source IP

Is it possibile to configure auditd to write/forward just one log for each executed command? For instance, if user **foobar** runs `rm -f /root/test.txt`, the written/forwarded log should be something like this:

```
2017-05-10 10:14 <SourceIP> foobar@<DestinationIP> rm -f /root/test.txt
```

Thanks,
Francesco